# Probability of a tail event on moments of normal random variables

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, distribution-tails

> Suppose $a_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ are iid. Then for any $\epsilon>0$ 
>    there is a constant $C >0$ such that $m \ge C\cdot n$ 
>    implies 
>   \begin{align}
> X_1 = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}\left(a^{2}_i - 1\right) &\le \epsilon \\ 
> X_2 = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}\left(a^{4}_i - 2\right) &\le \epsilon \\ 
> X_3 = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}a^{6}_i &< 10
> \end{align}
>    happen simultaneously with probability atleast $1 - 3n^{-2}$.

This is an intermediate step in proof on page 38 from a [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.1065) which is why the constants might look arbitrary or not tightest possible. The authors say it is a consequence of Chebyshev's inequality.

Here is my attempt at proving it. If we show that $\mathbb{P}\left[X_1 > \epsilon \right] \le 1/n^2$ and similarly inequalities for $X_2, X_3$ with $m \ge C\cdot n$ a union bound will give the result. However I am not able to prove the inequality even for $X_1$.

Clearly $\mathbb{E}\left[X_1\right] = 1$. Also variance of $X_1$ is,
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}\left[X_1\right] &= \frac{1}{m^2} \mathbb{E} \left[ \left(\sum_{i=1}^{m}\left(a^{2}_i - 1\right) \right)^2 \right] \\
&= \frac{1}{m^2}  \sum_{i=1}^{m}\mathbb{E} \left[\left(a^{2}_i - 1\right)^2 \right] \\
& = \frac{1}{m^2}  \sum_{i=1}^{m}\mathbb{E} \left[a^{4}_i + 1 - 2a_i^2 \right] \\
&= \frac{1}{m^2}  \sum_{i=1}^{m} (3 + 1 - 2) = \frac{2}{m}
\end{align}

By Chebyshev's inequality,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\left[X_1 > \epsilon \right] &\le \mathbb{P}\left[\left\lvert X_1\right\rvert > \epsilon \right] \\
&\le \frac{\operatorname{Var}\left[X_1\right]}{\epsilon^2} \\
&= \frac{2}{m\epsilon^2} \\
&\le \frac{2}{Cn\epsilon^2} \quad \text{using $m \ge Cn$} \\
&\le \frac{1}{n} \quad \text{for $C \ge 2\epsilon^{-2}$}
\end{align}

Comment: Hint: Instead of $$P(X_1>\epsilon)\leqslant\epsilon^{-2}E(X_1^2)$$ try to use $$P(X_1>\epsilon)\leqslant\epsilon^{-4}E(X_1^4)$$

Comment: @Did I verified that it works for $X_1$. It works because $X_1$ is sum of zero mean rvs. But for $X_2, X_3$ we need to subtract some terms on both sides. For eg., $\mathbb{P}\left[ X_2 \ge \epsilon \right] = \mathbb{P}\left[ X_2 - 1 \ge \epsilon-1 \right] $ which is not necessarily less than $ \mathbb{P}\left[ |X_2 - 1| \ge |\epsilon-1| \right]$ as $\epsilon - 1$ can be negative which we means we cannot use the raise to fourth power trick.

Comment: Indeed $E(a^4)=3$ and $E(a^6)=15$ hence $X_2\to3-2=1$ and $X_3\to15$ almost surely, which imply $P(X_2\le\epsilon)\to0$ and $P(X_3\le\epsilon)\to0$ when $m\to\infty$. One can suspect some typos here.